# What is maven-archetype-archetype and why is not available in mvnrepository?

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

I am trying to learn some Maven and especially how to create own archetypes. Then I came across the default ones provides by Maven. The archetype "org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-archetype" looked promising.

```
mvn archetype:generate \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-archetype \
    -DgroupId=my.test \
    -DartifactId=my-archetype \
    -Dpackage=my.archetype.package \
    -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

After the package was created there's a file `src/main/resources/archetype-resources/pom.xml` which uses the groupId, artifactId and version I passed as a parameter with a $ in front, like this:

```
<groupId>$my.test</groupId>
<artifactId>$my-archetype</artifactId>
<version>$1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

After installing it to the local repo catalog and using it to create a new Maven project based on it, it still has those dollar signs in it.

Now I am wondering: is this archetype out-dated? It's not mentioned often when you search the web. If not, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `maven-archetype-archetype` is an [archetype that contains a sample archetype](http://maven.apache.org/archetypes/maven-archetype-archetype/). A list of provided archetypes can be found [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html).

I suggest using the `quickstart archetype` if you are making a test archetype. This [example](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-repository.html), and this [guide](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/usage.html) will help you get set it up.

I am unsure why the `$` is still present in your `pom.xml` though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, i don't have some privileges such as to add a comment; that why i post this like an answer... I'm really sorry for that!
I wanted to know if you are using Netbeans IDE!
There is a way to create maven project with some configurations of course! 
But first of all; make me now if Netbeans its your IDE.

Comment: No, I'm not using any IDE. I wanted to understand it from the ground up.

Comment: Great, i suggest u to read this Guide to Creating Archetypes link https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html and  catch the essential about templating toolkit with this link https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html

Comment: you can still try the answer of jeremyz23

Comment: Why answer it? I upvoted it flagged it as answer because it explained me that maven-archetype-archetype is just an archetype which contains an archetype. I didn't realize it. But I have no further questions to this.